# Cursor en Android con SQLite Java

Tags: java, android, sqlite

**Buenas, tengo una consulta, estoy tratando de traer el valor en String de un Cursor. Paso a explicar un poco, estoy validando la existencia de una carga de datos. Si una patente ya existe el día de hoy, debe salir un anuncio que diga que ya existe, en caso de que no haya ninguna patente el día de hoy debe guardarse el dato. El problema, es que me sale el siguiente error:

```
Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

Así es como ocupo la validación desde el botón:

```
            try{
                if(patente.getText().length() == 6){
                    sqLiteProcesos.buscarDuplicado(fechaString,  seis, AgregarVehiculo.this, vehiculosClase);
                }else if(patente.getText().length() == 7){
                    sqLiteProcesos.buscarDuplicado(fechaString, siete, AgregarVehiculo.this, vehiculosClase);
                }
            }catch(Exception e) {
                Log.d("LOGD", "onCreate: " + e.getMessage());
            }
```

Y este es el método que utilizo para hacer esa validación:

**CÓDIGO ACTUALIZADO**

```
public boolean buscarDuplicado(String fechaHoy, String patente, Context context, VehiculosClase vehiculosClase){
    this.abridDBEscribir();
    String[] valorId = {String.valueOf(patente)};
    String consulta =
            "SELECT MAX(" + SQLiteVehiculoTabla.ID_PK_TABLA + ") "
            + "FROM " + SQLiteVehiculoTabla.TALLER_TABLA + " "
            + "WHERE " + SQLiteVehiculoTabla.PATENTE_AUTO + " LIKE '%'||?||'%'"
            + "AND " + SQLiteVehiculoTabla.DIA_INGRESO + " LIKE '%" + fechaHoy + "%'";
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(consulta, valorId);
    try{
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            String resultadoCursor = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteVehiculoTabla.ID_PK_TABLA));
            Toast.makeText(context, resultadoCursor, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("while", "buscarDuplicado: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se debe a que intentas acceder a tu cursor cuando este no tiene valores, la forma correcta de iterar y obtener los  elementos obtenidos en un cursor debe ser:

```
 while(cursor.moveToNext()){
           String resultadoCursor = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteVehiculoTabla.HORA_GUARDADO));
           Toast.makeText(context, resultadoCursor, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Por lo tanto tu método debería ser:

```
public boolean buscarDuplicado(String fechaHoy, String patente, Context context, VehiculosClase vehiculosClase){
     ...
     ...
     ...
    try{
       while(cursor.moveToNext()){
           String resultadoCursor = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("resultado"));
           Toast.makeText(context, resultadoCursor, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      }catch (Exception e){
         Log.d("while", "buscarDuplicado: " + e.getMessage());
      }
    cursor.close();
    return false;
}
```

---

Actualización:

De acuerdo a el error:

> Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Cuando realizas una consulta usando `MAX()` :

```
SELECT MAX(ID_PK_TABLA) FROM TALLER_TABLA WHERE  .....
```

Obtendrás un resultado entero, pero sin nombre de campo, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero en cambio si defines un "alias" como en este ejemplo "resultado":

```
 SELECT MAX(ID_PK_TABLA) AS resultado FROM TALLER_TABLA WHERE  .....
```

Obtendrás una descripción del campo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por lo tanto te sugiero realizar los siguientes cambios:

```
public boolean buscarDuplicado(String fechaHoy, String patente, Context context, VehiculosClase vehiculosClase){
    this.abridDBEscribir();
    String[] valorId = {String.valueOf(patente)};
    String consulta =
            "SELECT MAX(" + SQLiteVehiculoTabla.ID_PK_TABLA + ") AS resultado "
            + "FROM " + SQLiteVehiculoTabla.TALLER_TABLA + " "
            + "WHERE " + SQLiteVehiculoTabla.PATENTE_AUTO + " LIKE '%'||?||'%'"
            + "AND " + SQLiteVehiculoTabla.DIA_INGRESO + " LIKE '%" + fechaHoy + "%'";
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(consulta, valorId);
    try{
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            String resultadoCursor = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("resultado"));
            Toast.makeText(context, resultadoCursor, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("while", "buscarDuplicado: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: si, pero necesito validarlo con un if/else para que si encuentre haga un update y sino un insert

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta según tu respuesta pero me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Hola @FranqoBalsamo , revisa el cambio por favor.

Comment: Tienes razón me estaba olvidando del alias, muchas gracias

Comment: Excelente Franqo,, saludos!